# how to loop all collections of mongodb and data of collection inside loop in pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I am reading all collections of a mongodb database and the same time looping collection name in for loop to get each collection data dynamically using pymongo.

this is running on python 3.7 and mongodb 3.4 with pymongo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import json


client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017, maxPoolSize=50)
#print(client)
mydatabase = client["testdb"]

collections = mydatabase.collection_names(include_system_collections=False)

for collectionName in collections:
    print(collectionName)

    mydata = mydatabase.collectionName.find({})

    for value in mydata:
        print(value)
        for key,valueOFproject in value:
            print(key)
            print(value)
```

## Db

1st collection

```
{
    "_id" : "hiphdkTest_HIPHDK_76P1_P00_19WW09Test",
    "project" : "hiphdktest",
    "config" : "HIPHDK_76P1_P00_19WW09test",
    "manual" : {
        "tag1" : "fdsfsdfsd",
        "No" : "No",
        "prqdata1" : "fsdfadfasdfasdfsdfsd",
        "admin1" : "dbhiphdk"
    }
}
```

2nd collection

```
{
    "_id" : "hiphdk_HIPHDK_76P1_P00",
    "project" : "hiphdk",
    "config" : "HIPHDK_76P1_P00",
    "manual" : {
        "tag1" : "fdsfsdfsd",
        "No" : "No",
        "prqdata1" : "fsdfadfasdfasdfsdfsd",
        "admin1" : "dbhiphdk"
    }
}
```

3rd collection

```
{
    "_id" : "hiphdk_HIPHDK_76P1_P00_19WW09",
    "project" : "hiphdk",
    "config" : "HIPHDK_76P1_P00_19WW09",
    "manual" : {
        "tag1" : "fdsfsdfsd",
        "No" : "No",
        "prqdata1" : "fsdfadfasdfasdfsdfsd",
        "admin1" : "dbhiphdk"
    }
}
```

only getting collection names

hiphdk_HIPHDK_76P1_P00_19WW09
hiphdk_HIPHDK_76P1_P00
hiphdkTest_HIPHDK_76P1_P00_19WW09Test

it should print collection names and data of each collection.

Answer (score 2):

The key change is this line `mydata = mydatabase[collectionName].find({})`

See if this gives you what you need:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps

client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017, maxPoolSize=50)
mydatabase = client["testdb"]

collections = mydatabase.list_collection_names(include_system_collections=False)

for collectionName in collections:
    mydata = mydatabase[collectionName].find({})
    for value in mydata:
        print(dumps(value))
```